# Query to check all source status in node is complete?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This query deletes the node which has status complete but there are other status like incomplete or failed within the sources which gets deleted. How can I check whether all the sources in the node has status complete and delete the node?

```
MATCH (n:Sub)-[:HAS]->(s:Source{status:'COMPLETE'}) DETACH DELETE n
```

Comment: What do you mean by there are other statuses within the source?

Comment: There are multiple source with status failed or pending as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate all the sources with [COLLECT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and run a predicate with [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-all).

```
MATCH (sub:Sub)-[:HAS]->(source:Source)
WITH sub, COLLECT(source) AS sources 
WHERE ALL(src IN sources WHERE src.status = 'COMPLETE')
DETACH DELETE sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works. I found the predicate ALL but not sure how to use it. I'm new to cypher queries. I tested it with few other scenarios and it checked only if ALL the source has the particular status.